# NumberFormatter: strange behaviour with a minus sign in different locales

Tags: php, locale, number-formatting

I came across a problem with *Symfony/Form* which under the hood use `NumberFormatter` to format `NumberType` field. Our project is multilingual and for each country, we use a different locale.

`$formatter->format()` returns the different minus sign for negative numbers. For example:

```php
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('en', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$value = $formatter->format('-150');
var_dump($value); // string(4) "-150"

$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('lt', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$value = $formatter->format('-150');
var_dump($value); // string(6) "−150" <-- here is the problem
```

As you can see the `NumberFormatter` changes the minus sign to something else.

Why is it important for me? Because some elements on the page are generated with javascript, and js cannot parse `−150` number and returns `NaN`.

Can somebody explain the reason for this behaviour and how to get **correct** minus sign from `NumberFormatter` for *lt* locale?

Comment: Wow, so its spitting out the `\u2212` version of a standard dash/minus? Thats disgusting. You *could* jury rig a cleaner to `str_replace` it on output, but I'm sure someone more familiar with NumberFormatter has a better solution.

Comment: According to http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/lt-LT/index.html, the minus is `−` and for http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/en-GB/index.html it's `-`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. *Symfony/Form* has a great feature to add a [view transformers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html), which is rendered right before rendering a form element.

Here is my `FormType`:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('amount', NumberType::class, array(
        'required' => true,
        'scale' => 4,
    ));

    $builder->get('amount')->addViewTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function ($forward) {
            // Transform the lithuanian minus sign to the normal minus sign.
            return preg_replace('/\x{2212}/u', '-', $forward);
        },
        function ($reverse) {
            return $reverse;
        }
    ));

    // others form elements...
}
```

This approach allows to override the default view transformer for `\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType` which add spesific minus sign.

```php
$builder->addViewTransformer(new NumberToLocalizedStringTransformer(
    $options['scale'],
    $options['grouping'],
    $options['rounding_mode'],
    $options['html5'] ? 'en' : null
));
```

To be clear, the **view transformer** added in a custom form has higher priority over any others incorporated transformers.

It doesn't fix the problem in general for `NumberFormatter`, but help me fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about transforming to ascii?

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('lt', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$value = $formatter->format('-150');
$valueAsAscii = iconv('utf8', 'ascii//translit', $value);

var_dump($value);
var_dump($valueAsAscii);
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/bhcEf).

### output

```
string(6) "−150"
string(4) "-150"
```

### references

- [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Answer (score 0):

The real issue here is that the output from `NumberFormatter` is supposed to be **human-readable** according to the given locale, and not necessarily parseable as numeric. `\u2212` is the proper Unicode symbol for a minus sign, though only a handful of locales actually use it.

You *could* fix this specific problem by overriding the symbol:

```php
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('lt', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$formatter->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::MINUS_SIGN_SYMBOL, '-');
$value = $formatter->format('-150');
var_dump($value); // string(4) "-150"
```

However, consider the thousands separator, or decimal separator, which won’t necessarily parse in JavaScript either:

```php
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('lt', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$formatter->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::MINUS_SIGN_SYMBOL, '-');
$value = $formatter->format('-150000.5');
var_dump($value); // string(11) "-150 000,5"
```

You could override those symbols too, but the point here is that you should probably have a human-readable version according to the user’s locale, and a separate machine-readable version to be parsed by JavaScript.

If you still want to use `NumberFormatter` to output the machine-readable version, you could use the `'en'` locale for that but you would still need to override the grouping separator:

```php
$machineFormatter = new \NumberFormatter('en', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$machineFormatter->setSymbol(\NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, '');
```